# How can I allow user resize on elements within the window using Qt designer?

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt4, qt-designer, qtgui

I want to allow a user using my application to be able to drag a boundary between two widgets in my window which will resize the two (i.e. you drag it down and the top one will get bigger while the bottom gets smaller, and vice-versa).

Is there anything in Qt designer that will allow a user to resize an element in  the window, within certain constraints?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're describing is called a [`QSplitter`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsplitter.html) widget.  In Qt Designer, you can create one by **selecting 2 or more widgets**, and then clicking the splitter button on the toolbar at the top.  It's in the same location as the layout buttons.  It will place those widgets inside a `QSplitter`.  You still need to place the splitter widget inside another layout.  It will create a handle between them to let you resize the portion that each widget gets.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I wanted. Is there a way to set a default distribution for how large each widget within the splitter is?

Comment: You can using `moveSplitter` or `setSizes`, but not in Designer.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [QDockWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html). It can do all that you described above and more. The user can dock the widget to different sides of the window, changing which widget is on the top or bottom. You can customize the minimum and maximum sizes, as well as default sizes.